# Shows entire html page instead of showing 404 error in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

`login.html`

```
Username: <input type="text" ng-model="user.username"><br/>
Password: <input type="text" ng-model="user.password"> <br/>
<input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="login(user)">
```

`login.js`

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
   $scope.login = function(user){
     console.log(user);

       $http.post('/login', user)
       .success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
       });
   };
});
```

For first `console.log(user)` it shows username and password on console but after i do `console.log(response)`  it shows entire `index.html` page instead of showing 404 error, since there is no mapping for `/login` in the node server.

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',{
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
        })
        .when('/login',{
            templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Comment: this is a server side routing problem. Also doesn't make sense to use same route for API endpoint and for angular routing

Comment: @charlietfl yes you are right, after i removed `app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});` code from server.js which i used for angular $locationProvider, it works as supposed but can you please tell me how to fix that part in server which i removed.

Comment: suggest you create a route for your data only like `/api/****` and make sure to return 404 status if it is invalid. Might want to install one of the many different MEAN seed projects and see how they do all of this